# how to return true/false from nested jquery callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to validate elements inside a javascript function which contains two jQuery callback loops. Based on the conditions I want to return `true`/`false` from the inner jQuery loop and that should be sent back to the calling method of javascript. If the result of the inner loop is `true` the loop should stop running.

```
if(validate(key)){
}
else{
}
function validate(key) {
    $jquery.each(function(){
        $jquery.each(function(){
            if(){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false}
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're looking for, this will stop both loops when the `true` condition is met

```
function validate(key) {
    var result = false;
    $jquery.each(function(){
        $jquery.each(function(){
            if(){
                result = true;
                return false;//break inner loop
            }
        });
        if(result)
            return false; //break outer loop if we got true in inner
    });
    return result;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebLMU/)** You can open your console and see that the loop stops when the true condition is met

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate(key) {
    var result;
    $jquery.each(function() {
        $jquery.each(function() {
            if () {
                result = true;
            } else{
                result = false
            }
            return false;
        });
        if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But how can i stop iterations of both the jquery loops once i reach true, I tried using break based on result but did not work

Comment: The jQuery `each` function will stop its iterations if the called function returns `false`.

Comment: Won't this return the last value of `result`, regardless of what happened on the other iterations of `$.each()`?

Comment: @JeffB that's right, this answer does not accomplish what the OP needs

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) give a similar example. The docs state 'you can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false.'

So it sounds like you need to reverse you're terminology and return false when you want the loop to stop.

Let's say we have a bunch of `div` elements with `li` elements nested inside. If we wanted to stop the inner loop when it reaches an `li` with specific content we could do this:

```
  $( "div").each(function ( index, domEle) {
      $( "li", domEle ).each(function ( index, domEle2) {
        var areWeDone;
        $( domEle2 ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
              if ( $( domEle2 ).is(":contains('Here')") ) {
                result = true;
                return false;
              } else {
                result = false;
                return true;
              }
      });

      if (result == true) {
          return false;
      } 

  });
```

Here's the [full jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/UASkj/).

Comment: Your example works but it's not what the OP needs, you're reversing the semantics of the function by returning `false` when the condition is met

Answer (score -1):

```
    function validate(key) {
    var result;
    $jquery.each(function() {
        $jquery.each(function() {
            if () {
                result = true;

            } else{
                result = false;

            }
            return result;
        });
    });

}
```