# return false not working in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to prevent modal from reloading if there is an error in inputs?

```
 function functionTest(){
  $('#modal').modal('show');
    $('#submitButton').click(function() {
        $('.tee').each(function() {
            var x = $(this).val();
            if(x.length == 0){
                alert("empty fields");
                return false;
            }

         });    
    });
}
```

Comment: you're only returning false from the .each loop, not from the click event.

Comment: You're returning false from the `.each` - you need to return false at the level of the `click`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to return true/false from nested jquery callback functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141157/how-to-return-true-false-from-nested-jquery-callback-functions) - This question features your exact issue (returning false to an outer function from within a jQuery `.each`)

Comment: oh I see. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only returning false from the .each loop, not from the click event. The easiest way to solve it is to set an intermediary flag, which the loop can update, and then return the value of the flag:

```
function functionTest() {
  $('#modal').modal('show');
  $('#submitButton').click(function() {
    var retVal = true; //flag assumes everything's ok, to start with
    $('.tee').each(function() {
        var x = $(this).val();
        if(x.length == 0){
            alert("empty fields");
            retVal = false; //set flag false when we find a problem
            return false;
        }
     });    

     return retVal;
   });
}
```